# Expanding packed nibbles to 5-bit groups

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

I currently have an un unsigned int of 64 bits that contains:

```
0100
0100
0100
0100
0000...
```

And i would change it to :

```
01000
01000
01000
01000
00000...
```

Is there a way to to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: It's really hard to tell what your asking for - are those supposed to be the top 5 nibbles of your uint, and the rest is all 0? If so, I'd extract the 16 nibbles, shift each one bit to the left and reassemble.

Comment: I can't really do that because it's a representation of a geometric shape. when the bit is set a 0 there is nothing and when  the bit is set at 1 there is something

Comment: Are you doing this on modern hardware with access to modern instructions? Haswell (and newer) and Ryzen have `PDEP` which can do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

📎 Hi! It looks like you are trying to expand 4-bit nibbles into 5-bit groups.

In general, you can do it like this

```
uint64_t value = YOUR_DATA;  //this has your bits.
for (int i; i< sizeof(value)*2; i++) {
   uint8_t nibble = (value & 0xF);
   nibble <<= 1; //shift left 1 bit, add 0 to end.
   STORE(nibble, i);
   value>>=4;  //advance to next nibble         
}
```

This will call `STORE` once for each group of 4 bits. The arguments to STORE are the "expanded" 5 bit value, and the nibble counter, where 0 represents the least significant 4 bits.

The design question to answer is how to store the result? 64 bits / 4 * 5 = 80 bits, so you either need 2 words, or to throw away the data at one end.

Assuming 2 words with the anchor at the LSB, STORE could look like

```
 static uint64_t result[2] = {0,0};
 void STORE(uint64_t result[], uint8_t value, int n) {
    int idx = (n>12);                //which result word?
    result[idx] |= value << ( n*5 - idx*64 );
    if (n==12) result[1] |= value>>4; //65th bit goes into 2nd result word
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Omit the leading 0, it serves no purpose => shift left one bit

Comment: I can't because it's a representation of a shape so if i remove the leading 0 it will not have the same shape :/

Comment: There literally is no way to use a leading 0 in binary, you have to be more specific for what you want to achieve

Comment: @PieerotGG If you want to use them in a string or something and not process as a binary representation of a number: format the string to have a fixed length and input the left shifted number

Comment: Okay so:

i use the int64 to store pieces of tetris:

i now the width of my tetrimino (piece of tetris) and i want to be able change it without changing the shape of my tetrimino. So i need to add a 0 at each end of line.

Sorry for my english i'm French :)

Comment: @PieerotGG ah got it: use a matrice, in case you're using Python numpy has what you're after. Essentially multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Nop I can't it's for performances. The process is really greedy so we prefer to store them into ints

Comment: There is no such thing as an "end of line" within the bits of a uint. I think you need to explain your problem with more detail and examples of what should happen for particular inputs. Don't forget to post the code you've tried so far.

Comment: It's how Image processing usually is done, I regularly use it for computer vision sfuff with Python that runs in real-time. If implemented in C or something it will be even less of a concern. But if you want to stick with the bare int and need leading 0s I'm afraid I can't help you(and I doubt the 0s still are there once you store it as uint except you format it when reading back)